# Elasticsearch query with merging an array

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got data in Elasticsearch in format as below:

```
{
  "_index":"app",
  "_type":"users",
  "_id":"AV-tzC3nh2uOQJaRfve5",
  "_score":1.0,
  "_source":
    {
      "name":"user1",
      "messages":
      [
        {
          "text":"my"
        },
        {
          "text":"name"
        },
        {
          "text":"is"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

I would like to get user that posted messages containing "myname" when they are merged. What is the best way to do it in Elasticsearch?